# replace the word in the array with given value

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the array variable `$geo_detail=Array ( [0] => nsu [1] => us east [2] => us west )`
I want to replace `nsu with NSU` ,`us east to US East` and `us west to US West`

I have tried as

```
if (count($geo_detail))
          {
              foreach($geo_detail as $geos=>$key){
                  if (str_word_count($key) =='1')
                     $key= strtoupper($key);
                  elseif((str_word_count($key) =='2'))
                   $key= ucwords($key); 
              }
          }
         return $geo_detail;
```

but return `Array ( [0] => nsu [1] => us east [2] => us west )`

how to replace the array value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the real Key/Value from your array, replace

```
$key= strtoupper($key);
```

to

```
geo_detail[$geos] = strtoupper($key);
```

and

```
$key= ucwords($key);
```

to

```
geo_detail[$geos] = ucwords($key);
```

Comment: The result with the changes is
array (3) {[0] => string (3) "NSU" [1] => string (7) "Us East" [2] => string (7) "Us West"} and not US East and US West as required in the task !

Comment: this is to update his array, not to do his work about capitalize

Answer (score 0):

```
$geo =  ['nsu', 'us west', 'us east'];

foreach ($geo as $k => $g) {
    
    // explode string
    $words = explode(" ", $g);
    
    $string = "";
    foreach($words as $w) {
        
        // 3 chars and below, all caps
        if (strlen($w) <= 3) {
            $w = strtoupper($w);
        } else {
            
            $w = ucwords($w);
        }
        
        $string = $string . $w . " ";
    }
    
    
    // assign new value, remove space at end
    $geo[$k] = substr($string, 0, -1);
}

print_r($geo);
```

Result

```
Array ( [0] => NSU [1] => US West [2] => US East )
```

Answer (score 0):

The words must be treated separately. I understand the task as follows:

With the first word everything should be capitalized, with the second word only the first letter.

I also used explode() for splitting.

```
$geo_detail = ['nsu','us east','us west'];

$result = [];
foreach($geo_detail as $key => $item){
  $wordArr = explode(' ',$item);
  $new = strtoupper($wordArr[0]);
  if(isset($wordArr[1])){
    $new .= " ".ucwords($wordArr[1]);
  }
  $result[$key] = $new;
}

$expected = ['NSU','US East','US West'];
var_dump($result === $expected);//bool(true)
```